# Count differently an event if the same event from the same user happened in the past

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table listing subscription events. When there is a "NEW" event added to the table, it means either a new subscription from a brand new customer OR the renewal of a monthly subscription from an existing customer.
I want to be able to be able to summarize the data by month and split it depending on whether that is a new customer or just a renewal.

I am looking for a formula that says "if the user_ID is unknown and the event is "NEW", then count `+1` in the "new customer" column, otherwise `+1` in the "renewal" column

**SOURCE TABLE**

| User_id | Event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NEW | 26/9/2021 |
| 2 | NEW | 26/8/2021 |
| 1 | NEW | 15/8/2021 |

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Sept 20: 1 renewal; 0 new subscriptions
Aug 20: 2 new subscriptions
```

Comment: Let me give you an idea. I developed an application for inventory management. In one of the classes, a user is asked about the type of transaction. If it's issuing or receiving. if he's receiving, he's asked if it's a new supply or item returned. Now whether it's newly supplied or just returned, what I use in determining the plus and minus of the transaction is the issue or receive transaction type, not the newly supplied or returned subtype. But all records get saved in the database for clarity. Now, try to apply same logic.

Comment: Sorry for the crappy looking post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a window function `MIN` to determine the earliest subscription date for each user and compare that to determine whether they are a new user or not. You may then aggregate/sum on this to determine the number of new subscriptions or renewals per year and month.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(`Date`) as `year`,
    MONTH(`Date`) as `month`,
    SUM(is_new=true) as `new subscriptions`,
    SUM(is_new=false) as `renewals`
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        `Date`=MIN(`Date`) OVER (PARTITION BY `User_id`) as is_new 
    FROM
        events
    WHERE 
        `Event`='NEW'
) e
GROUP BY
   YEAR(`Date`),
   MONTH(`Date`)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(`Date`),
   MONTH(`Date`);
```

| year | month | new subscriptions | renewals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021 | 9 | 0 | 1 |

---

or if you are using a mysql version which does not support window functions you may perform a left join on a subquery that finds the earliest subscription date. Using the same logic, the we can determine and count the number of new and renewed subscriptions.

```sql
SELECT
    YEAR(`Date`) as `year`,
    MONTH(`Date`) as `month`,
    SUM(new_sub.min_date IS NOT NULL) as `new subscriptions`,
    SUM(new_sub.min_date IS NULL) as `renewals`
FROM 
    events e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        `User_id`,
        MIN(`Date`) as min_date
    FROM
        events
    WHERE 
        `Event`='NEW'
    GROUP BY
        `User_id`
) as new_sub ON e.`User_id`=new_sub.`User_id` AND
                e.`Date`=new_sub.min_date
GROUP BY
   YEAR(`Date`),
   MONTH(`Date`)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(`Date`),
   MONTH(`Date`)
```

| year | month | new subscriptions | renewals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021 | 9 | 0 | 1 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x2pJYj5gX1L1YhHZFAzkEM/1)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ggordon for this. We are still on mySQL 5.7 so your second option worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify if a row is the first one for each client.

For example you can do:

```
select
  year(date) as y,
  month(date) as m,
  sum(case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as new_subscriptions,
  sum(case when rn <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as renewals
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by user_id order by date) as rn 
  from t 
  where event = 'NEW'
) x
group by y, m
order by y, m
```

Result:

```
 y     m  new_subscriptions  renewals 
 ----- -- ------------------ -------- 
 2021  8  2                  0        
 2021  9  0                  1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ikMm3pjNHbC4CeQbU9L3C/0).

Comment: Thanks @The Impaler